# Repeating a python script in a specific point

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to make a small script which makes basic mathematical operations, and I want it to return to the number input depending if the user want or not to make another operation based on another input. I've already tried **while** loops and defining a **function**

**Here is the code:**

```
    print('Hi!,this is a calculator')

#Here's where it should return

num1 = input('Please,enter a number ')
num2 = input('Enter another number ')

while True:

    operator = input('Insert an operator +,-,*,/ ')

    if operator != "+" and operator != "-" and operator != "*" and operator != "/":
                
        print('Invalid Operator')
          
    else:
            
        if operator == "+":

            result = int(num1) + int(num2)
            result = str(result)

            print('Your result is ' + result)


        elif operator == "-":

            result = int(num1) - int(num2)
            result = str(result)

            print('Your result is ' + result)


        elif operator == "*":

            result = int(num1) * int(num2)
            result = str(result)

            print('Your result is ' + result)

        elif operator == "/":

            result = int(num1) / int(num2)
            result = str(result)

            print('Your result is ' + result) 

        exit()

#Here's the repeating input

# repeat = input('Do you want to make another operation? Y/N ')

# repeat = repeat.lower()

# if repeat == 'y' or repeat == 'yes':
                
    


# else:
#     exit()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You may want to shorten your code to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Currently, it is difficult to pinpoint where your specific issue is with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it right. You can use a function to do the calculation, and call the function in a loop. If the user is finished, then break the loop.

EDIT: Added a loop to `calculate()` per the asker's specifications

```
print('Hi!, this is a calculator')

def calculate():
    # loop in case the user entered an incorrect operator
    while True:
        num1 = input('Please,enter a number ')
        num2 = input('Enter another number ')
        operator = input('Insert an operator +,-,*,/ ')
        if operator != "+" and operator != "-" and operator != "*" and operator != "/":
            print('Invalid Operator')
            continue  # restart the calculation
        else:
            if operator == "+":
                result = int(num1) + int(num2)
                result = str(result)
                print('Your result is ' + result)
            elif operator == "-":
                result = int(num1) - int(num2)
                result = str(result)
                print('Your result is ' + result)
            elif operator == "*":
                result = int(num1) * int(num2)
                result = str(result)
                print('Your result is ' + result)
            elif operator == "/":
                result = int(num1) / int(num2)
                result = str(result)
                print('Your result is ' + result)
        return  # Finished with this calculation

# continuously calculate until the user doesn't say yes
while True:
    calculate()
    repeat = input('Do you want to make another operation? Y/N ').lower()
    if repeat != 'y' and repeat != 'yes':
        break
```

Comment: Almost there,the problem now is that in you enter a wrong operation input it takes directly to "Do you want to make another operation?" Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: You're free to change it to do what you want, but you didn't specify what you wanted to happen then - do you want to just restart the function automatically? If so you can wrap everything in the function in a `while True` loop, put a `return` statement at the end of the function, and a `continue` in the case of an invalid operator. I can show how that's done but for now you haven't specified what you actually want to happen instead.

Comment: Nice and done! I have edited and placed the loops in the right place,i am pretty newbie so please sorry for the blank spaces. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ZajRJ I changed my example to reflect what you were asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Make two functions and put both functions in a loop.

```
def calculate(n1,n2):
 oper = input("Enter operand: ")

 #your if-elif block here
      ....

      ....
 print("Your result is", ....)

 


def userInput():
 num1 =  input("Enter first num: ")
 num2 =  input("Enter second num: ")

 return [num1,num2]


while True:
 inlist = userInput()
 calculate(inlist[0],inlist[1])

 answer = input("Do you want another operation?")
 if answer == "Y":
  continue
 else:
  exit()
```